# Has my domain been hijacked?

Tags: domain-name-system, hijack

I own http://festivals.ie. I had a festivals website on this domain hosted on a VPS, but I shut it down a couple of years ago. Now when I go to this domain, I get the same webpage that appears at http://mk-s.org/.

I've checked and it seems that I still own the domain, so I don't understand how http://mk-s.org/ appear to have gained control of it?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the IP of your old VPS was reused for another customer.

I'd just change the DNS entry for your domain to point to a webspace showing a domain parking site or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you suggest an appropriate site that I would point this domain towards?

Comment: Sorry, no. If you don't have a suitable server available, a small web space package should do it. Maybe the hoster of your domain has something fitting available.

Comment: OK, I thought there might be something canonical like http://example.org that people use

Comment: Just point it to 127.0.0.1.